# Android noise cancelling microphone access

Tags: android, microphone

How can I access the microphone used for noise cancellation from my Android application?

As the noise cancellation microphone is on the border of hardware/software, building a custom Android image is not out of the question as it may be needed.

Comment: This might be only a hardware implementation and likely you can't access it via software.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does noise cancellation work in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975167/how-does-noise-cancellation-work-in-android)